# Javascript href MVC Razor URL.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my javascript, trying to go to an Url.Action using javascript.

```
function selectSchool() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("SelectSchool", "Home", new { school = "_id_" })'.replace('_id_', $("#schoolSelect").val());
    alert(url);
    window.location.href = url;
    }
```

The link in the alert looks fine, however the url goes back to the current view Home/Index?
What am i doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="selectSchool()">Välj</button>
```

Comment: Should work. How is this called? Maybe a form is submitting after the funtion finishes?

Comment: can you provide sample `url` before and after replacing, and how you call this func?

Comment: <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="selectSchool()">Välj</button>
No sumbit

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson by default - button send submit if you not specify `type` attribute, also add this markup to your post

Comment: Try with `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="selectSchool()">Välj</button>`

Comment: I'm inclined to think two things, form submission - which is possible. Also routes, is your routing config setup correctly, have you defined you controller properly, go back to basics and work your way through and you may find the answer.

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson : What happens if you copy the url(as you see in your alert) and paste to browser url? Are you able to navigate as expected?

Comment: can you include the output Javascript lines?